# SSRS Word Clouds

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

We are currently integrating with SQL Server Reporting Services and have got most of the functionality we require in place now but I am stumped on how do get the last bit working. On the current manual system at the bottom of the Excel spreadsheet is a Word Cloud which we would like to emulate in SSRS. I have constructed a DataSet that returns a list of words and their scores but I cannot work out how to create a word cloud from it.

I have followed the example below and got it working successfully and it looks great in Visual Studio but when I look at it in Excel and as a PDF its just not very nice at all.

http://www.sqljason.com/2012/03/making-tag-cloud-with-ssrs-rich-text.html

The main problem is that the results are loaded into a table (that has to be shrunk so it is unobtrusive) the some VB generates the HTML that is then rendered in a Text Area.

When I look at it in Excel the table is clearly visible (its huge) and in PDF form it is missing.

Does anyone know of an extension or plugin that I could use to display the word cloud or a better way of doing it?

The alternative would be to embed it as an image and call a web-service that creates the word cloud on the fly but it does seem like a lot of work for something that is probably a fairly common requirement.

Thanks everyone in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You say it does not look nice and then that it is missing.  Which one?  Why are you having to use a Dataset for words generated?  If they are just arbitrary words you could set them up in free floating text boxes.  I am not getting why to generate text you need to apply a dataset to it unless there is an object like a 'list' you have rules that you HAVE TO use a dataset.

Without a picture (which you do not have enough points to show) it is hard to tell what the cross applicatin problem could be.  You are using a blog as a basis which the person could be using 2008R2 or 2012 SSRS for as well which makes it hard to troubleshoot.

My guess is you are applying a boxing layer, positioning or overlay that the PDF renderer does not like. My suggestion would be to start a small report with just his example only and see if it works as is in 2008.  He seems to have someone mention on an issue of positioning which is the biggest culprit of problems with SSRS and multi format saving.  If you can get the CORE part of your report working as he described I would think you may be able to use that as a 'subreport' inside of another report if you want more than one object to a report.